# Which is positive? Green or black?

Tags: wiring

I tried cutting my old Gameboy Advance SP Charger wires out since the adaptor doesn't work anymore. I am planning to attach it on a USB cord to replace the adaptor.

I have noticed that the wires aren't colored red and black which is the usual.

The wires are enclosed in a single black wire and inside there was a color green wire and a naked wire.

I want to know which is the positive and which is the negative among the two.

[image: Graphical Representation]

[image: Actual Photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I bet on the green one to be the positive.
But don't trust me, use a multimeter to check the connection from the linkout port to your two wires.

Here's the pinout of the GBA side port, from this you can understand the pins on the charger's cable and check the connection to the wires:
[image]

Comment: It works. It's charging. :)